# Changing the colour of graph in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the below graph, I want to change the colour of the left graph as red, and the right graph as blue. How can I simply do that using the below command? Many thanks in advance.

```
normgraph <- ggplot (data=data1, aes (x=x1)) +
  geom_density() + 
  geom_density(data=data2, aes(x=x2)) +
  labs(title="The variation of grain weight") + 
  labs (y="Frequency(%)") + 
  labs (x="Grain weight (mg)") + 
  lims(x=c(50,70))
```

[image]

Comment: Look into ?scale_fill_manual

Answer (score 0):

Since data is not provided, I will use `iris` to illustrate how to do this. Note that code is similar to yours; I just haven't included any further customizations relevant for your plot (as they depend on your dataset).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_density(color = "blue") +
  geom_density(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width), color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Probably needs a fill and not col.